# Unable to build apk file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to build apk but I'm unable to create it.Getting the following errors.But project running successfully.my android studio version 2.2.2

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/common/api/zzd.class

## my gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wedding.weddingapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        configurations { all*.exclude module: 'gson-2.5' }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/layerhq/releases-android/master/releases/" }
    maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/layerhq/Atlas-Android/master/releases/" }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.layer.atlas:layer-atlas:0.3.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting

> TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/common/api/zzd.class

You should use latest version of **[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)**

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

and use

```
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

Thean **Clean-Rebuild-Restart** your IDE

Comment: why i am getting this error?This error related to what?

Comment: Actuall my collegue is working with code she able to build apk,my self i unable to build.

Comment: @m.v.n.kalyani multiple same `dependency` calling in  `build.gradle` section

Comment: where i am calling i did not found.Can you help

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.layer.atlas:layer-atlas:0.3.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'

Comment: @m.v.n.kalyani `clean-rebuild-restart` your IDE

Comment: 1000 times i did.Ok for your  suggesion i willl do now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135047/discussion-between-m-v-n-kalyani-and-intellij-amiya).